# Next.js Image Optimization at Build time for Webp format

Tags: image, optimization, build, next.js, web-config

Im using next-optimized-images
https://github.com/cyrilwanner/next-optimized-images#optimizeimagesindev

My site is static. (next export)

My next.config.js file looks like

```js
const withOptimizedImages = require("next-optimized-images");
module.exports = withOptimizedImages({
  optimizeImagesInDev: true,
})
```

any idea why my .webp files aren't working - they just load the default .jpg files.

My folder path for images looks like :

```
/public
  /images
    /architect
      /header-image.jpg
      /header-image.webp
```

Current error :

```js
Module not found: Can't resolve './images/architect/Header-Image.webp'
  249 |         <picture>
  250 |           <source
> 251 |             srcSet={require("./images/architect/Header-Image.webp")}
      |                    ^
  252 |             type="image/webp" 
  253 |           />
  254 |           <source
```

Current implementation

```js
        <picture >
          <source
            srcSet={require("./images/architect/Header-Image.JPG?webp")}
            type="image/webp" 
          />
          <source
            srcSet={require("./images/architect/Header-Image.JPG")}
            type="image/jpeg"
          />
          <img
            src={require("./images/architect/Header-Image.JPG?")}
          />
        </picture>
```

Comment: 1> What is `web.config` that you've referred to? It should be in `next.config.js`. 2> Your relative file path appears to be wrong. (Shouldn't it be something like `../public/images/---`? Although I'm not sure how things work in `next-optimized-images`, but in general Node.js resolution, this would have definitely be an error.) 3> Check if your filesystem is case-sensitive or not.

Comment: file name is Header-Image.webp 

next.js handles ../public/images as /images but i'm unsure how next-optimized-images does so perhaps there is some testing to be down there to figure that out.